# How to change color qr generating to another color of black like green red etc

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, qr-code

**Problem**

**How to change color of generating qr to red or green or blue(another color of black)**

I working in visual studio 2015 windows form application

I generating qr using message toolkit library and it working good without any problem

**only i face problem how to change color qr code using message toolkit**

**my code**

**Last update**

**i try to replace color to red but result convert all image to red
actually i need to display qr but with another color**

```
MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder encoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();
                    encoder.QRCodeScale = 8;
                    Bitmap bmp = ChangeColor(encoder.Encode(textBox1.Text), Color.Red);
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    bmp.Save(sv.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 public static Bitmap ChangeColor(Bitmap scrBitmap, Color color)
        {
            //You can change your new color here. Red,Green,LawnGreen any..  
            Color newColor = color;
            Color actualColor;
            //make an empty bitmap the same size as scrBitmap  
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(scrBitmap.Width, scrBitmap.Height);
            for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    //get the pixel from the scrBitmap image  
                    actualColor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                    // > 150 because.. Images edges can be of low pixel colr. if we set all pixel color to new then there will be no smoothness left.  
                    if (actualColor.A > 150)
                        newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
                    else
                        newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, actualColor);
                }
            }
            return newBitmap;
        }
    Result wrong result
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe replace the color in the resulting bitmap?

Comment: how to replace color if possible can you help me

Comment: did the problems solve ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your example code is that you are using the alpha channel to decide whether or not to change a pixel. But since the generated image is fully opaque, every pixel will have an alpha value of 255.

The gradient at the edges is achieved by using appropriate RGB colors to achieve a grayscale between black and white. If you just changed your code to use `actualColor.R` instead of `A`, it would actually change the colors of the black parts to red correctly (but remove most of the smooth gradients).

To keep the gradients, you should properly tint the image instead of using a hard if-condition at each pixel. Properly tinting means that you multiply each RGB channel of the source color with each respective RGB channel of the target color.

However, since you wish to tint the dark parts only and not the white ones, we need to invert the source image colors first. Since black is represented as RGB (0,0,0), multiplying it with the target color won't change anything - multiplying anything by 0 is still 0. White on the other hand uses RGB (255,255,255), so it will completely use the target color (without changing it in any way). If it was anything in between black and white, you'd get the respective mix of the source and destination color.

The multiplication (and dealing with colors in general) works better if each color channel is represented as floating point number in the range from 0 to 1, so we divide the original value of source and target by 255 before the multiplication and multiply it by 255 afterwards to pass it to the `Color.FromARGB(int,int,int)` function.

I made the following code example a little more verbose than needed, so things become more clear.

```
public static Bitmap ChangeColor(Bitmap scrBitmap, Color newColor)
{
    // make an empty bitmap the same size as scrBitmap  
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(scrBitmap.Width, scrBitmap.Height);
    for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.Width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.Height; j++) {
            // get the pixel from the scrBitmap image  
            var actualColor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);

            // invert colors, since we want to tint the dark parts and not the bright ones
            var invertedOriginalR = 255 - actualColor.R;
            var invertedOriginalG = 255 - actualColor.G;
            var invertedOriginalB = 255 - actualColor.B;

            // multiply source by destination color (as float channels)
            int r = (invertedOriginalR / 255) * (newColor.R / 255) * 255;
            int g = (invertedOriginalG / 255) * (newColor.G / 255) * 255;
            int b = (invertedOriginalB / 255) * (newColor.B / 255) * 255;
            var tintedColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
            newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, tintedColor);
        }
    }
    return newBitmap;
}
```